# Finding which vertexes are not listed when given "Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame" in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing node information and another containing edge information. However, when I try to craft a data frame I get the error: "Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame". I've found many ways to fix this problem on this site but I was wondering if there was any code that would display the actual vertex names that are not listed in the vertex dataframe.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Even if it's just    dput(head(df, 20)) , the output is probably too big as it is about 120 rows.

Comment: If the full dataframe is 120 rows, don't worry, `head(df, 20)` are the first 20. And if it's too big because it has lots of columns, subset the df and post only the ones relevant to the question.